# how to create a tutorial app in android? I am really confused how text and images stored in?

Tags: android, view

[App from play-store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thugian.eb.learnphp&hl=en)

The above link's app has been taken from one play store. I need to create a app like this tutorial app.

How to display the information like this image when I hit a button or selecting a item from the list?

Comment: Look http://www.vogella.com/tutorials.html tutorial, they will help you.

Comment: but my doubt is how to store the pages like tat and retrieve?

Comment: please @KostyaKhuta  I am in a need of creating a tutorial application..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all you must have [Database](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) and fill it with your data and images ( path to image on SD card/ int value of image/ url where it saved).
2. You must create [listView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) with chapters and fill listView with data from database using SimpleCursorAdapter. Add onItemClickListener to your listView for checking clicks on listView.
3. Create Activity/Fragment for displaying information. Sample. If user click on chapter 5 in listView you make Select query to your Database an display all text in you form.
   I hope it will help you.

   String summary = "your html code";

   webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);

Edited2:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/htmltest.html");
```

htmltest.html

```
<img border="0" src="../res/drawable-hdpi/test.png" alt="nothing" width="304" height="228" />
```

Comment: database means SQLite? but SQLite store in the form of tables.. how to store the webpages?

Comment: yes SQLite. read more about element WebView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: bro.. please understand my problem... WebView can be used online and custom html code.. but when I try to store the full webpage in offline using webview how to do?

Comment: it is ease. Watch my edited answer

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2010/02/php-login-script-with-encryption.html please visit this site.. I want to display this tutorial like a webpage.. if I do as wat u said only a line of text can be stored.. in my point I need to show the page.. clear this doubt please...

Comment: pff. this code for web page on PHP it is not for android.

Comment: yeah... I know.. hey wat I told... I want to create a tutorial app in android for PHP.. how to use the drawable folder images in this html code? tell me the path like how to retrieve drawable folder images?

Comment: watch my editer ansewer. Please, check my answer and press +1

Comment: please make +1 for my answer and press mark( check) element near it. Do you know ho do it?